# How do I code for an arbitrary sound equivalent to a frequency value on a seek bar to play in android?

Tags: android

When I run this class on my android phone or emulator, the application does not even start.
I would really appreciate any improvements :)

```
public class Whistly extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar seekBar;
private Button k5;
private Button k10;
private Button k15;
private Button k20;
private ToggleButton whistle;
private TextView frequency;

private Integer intToneFreq = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));

private final int duration = 2; // seconds
private final int sampleRate = 8000;
private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
private  int freqOfTone = intToneFreq * 1000; // hz

private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_whistly);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    k5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.k5);
    k10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.k10);
    k15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.k15);
    k20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.k20);
    whistle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    frequency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    seekBar.setMax(25);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    k5.setOnClickListener(this);
    k10.setOnClickListener(this);
    k15.setOnClickListener(this);
    k20.setOnClickListener(this);
    whistle.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.whistly, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == k5) {
        frequency.setText(R.string.k5);
        seekBar.setProgress(5);
    }

    if (v == k10) {
        frequency.setText(R.string.k10);
        seekBar.setProgress(10);
    }

    if (v == k15) {
        frequency.setText(R.string.k15);
        seekBar.setProgress(15);
    }

    if (v == k20) {
        frequency.setText(R.string.k20);
        seekBar.setProgress(20);
    }

    if (v == whistle) {
        if(whistle.isChecked()){
            playSound();
        }

    }

}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Use a new tread as this can take a while
    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            genTone();

        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

void genTone() {
    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] =  Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

    }
}

void playSound() {
    final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
    audioTrack.play();
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
       String progress1 = String.valueOf(progress);
       frequency.setText(progress1 + " kHz");
   }

   @Override
   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

   }

}
```

Comment: Your first step in any such case should be to use the logcat tool to find out why the application has crashed on launch.  Or did it fail to fully build and deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
private Integer intToneFreq = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
```

In a static initializer; at the point early in execution when that runs, you don't yet have any content view to contain an inflated SeekBar, and you haven't yet pointed your seekBar variable at it.

You may be able to solve your immediate problem simply by initializing intToneFreq to some safe default value, and only trying to read the progress bar once your app is fully started up.  But it's quite likely you will find other issues as well.  As mentioned in comments, you'll need to learn to use the logcat tool and/or the source debugger.